# How can I set the current value of vCPUs lower with Citrix XenServer 8.2?

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, citrix

I've setup my VM as so:

[image]

Note: It's initial number of vCPU is 2

Later, I increase it but notice that there's no way to decrease it:

[image]

Question: Is there any way to change the current number of vCPUs while it's running via CLI?

I think one goal I have is to adjust this number based on the VMs overall CPU utilization. For instance, if this VM was relatively idle, I would want other VMs on the server to benefit from more vCPUs instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the Linux/Windows API CLI for remote management [How to install](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-hypervisor/command-line-interface.html#installing-the-xe-cli)

Then you can use it from your Linux/Windows machine.

Once installed, you can get the UUID of the VM by name :

```
xe vm-list name-label=<vm_name>
```

Change the current VCPUs(should be lower than max Vcpus):

```
# No shutdown is needed for increasing
# Shutdown is needed for reducing
xe vm-param-set VCPUs-at-startup=<vcpus_no> uuid=<vm_uuid>
```

Change the maximum VCPUs:

```
# Shutdown is needed for both operations
xe vm-param-set VCPUs-max=<max_vcpus_no> uuid=<vm_uuid>
```

Comment: Interestingly, using `xe vm-param-set VCPUs-at-startup` does seem to let me reduce it but it does it seem to commit the property and change it. If I run that but then go to remote desktop and hit "save" then it seems to actually change it dynamically. Seems like an additional step is required after setting the at startup value.

Comment: I see forgot to state that a shutdown is needed in order to reduce VCPUs number. I will update the answer.

Comment: It's actually not! You can change the number using that command, then the dropdown in the UI changes! You can then lower the CPUs. It's almost like a bug that works. There must be another command to commit the new number even if it's lower.

Comment: Weird, is Vpcu hotplug enabled in your case ?